# Type TranslateModule does not have 'ɵmod' property

Tags: angular, typescript, translate, ngx-translate

Im trying to implement ngx-translate in an angular proyect, but it always throw this error on console "Type TranslateModule does not have 'ɵmod' property." i dont know what to do.

I already installed npm install 'npm install @ngx-translate/core --save' and '@ngx-translate/http-loader --save'

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { EventsComponent } from './events/events.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http,'./../assets/i18n',".json");
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [           
    AppComponent,
      NavComponent,
      EventsComponent,
      HomeComponent
   ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "argentinite": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/argentinite",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "argentinite:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "argentinite:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "argentinite:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "argentinite"
}
```

Comment: Can you share **package.json** in the question to specify the **Angular** and **ngx-translate** version that you used? Suspect of the version incompatibility issue.

Comment: there is, thanks for the help

Comment: Hi there, you attach the wrong file, that was **angular.json**.

Comment: This may helps: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/13958

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it seems that you're using an incompatible version of `ngx-translate` with your Angular version.

You can choose the version corresponding to your Angular version depending on the following version table:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core#installation